# Dockerfile facing issues while implementing in azure devops

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I have asp.net core project developed in my machine with docker support. The docker file resides in my project.

i.e, its placed outside the modules and under the rootfolder.
This image is working perfectly fine when I run using Visual studio.

```js
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication4.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication4.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication4.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication4.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication4.dll"]
```

I have created a pipeline in Azure Devops. and pushed the same code the way it is in my system, to azure git repository. but it fails to at workdir itself.
What is that I am missing here?

Comment: try `workdir /src` -- that's no quotes and no dot

Comment: yes it fixed the issue. how do I mark this as answer?

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help. I've voted to close this as a typo though.